# align divs in columns and rows without bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I have the following fiddle.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ba1mr4sL/1/)

I need the alignment as following image.

[image]

My CSS is as follows. I am not able to align it in a row and column structure.

```
#part1 {
  width: 15%;
  float: left;
}
#part2 {
  width: 85%;
  float: left;
}
.success {
  background-color: #0ae;
  border-radius: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  border: 4px solid #10e619;
}
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.row:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Css Grid To achieve this.

[Complete Guide To CSS Grid Here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

First: Add this to ``:

```
grid-template-areas: /* Define Areas */
      "logo l1 l1"
      "logo l2 l3"
      "logo l4 l5"
      "logo l6 l6";
    justify-items: center; /* Fill Horizontally */
    align-items: center;  /* Center Vertically */
    grid-gap: 10px; /* Center spaces between items */
```

Then Define the area to each element By:

1- adding it to html like :

```
<div class="label label1">
    content for label 1
</div>
```

then define the area in css:

```
.label1 {
   grid-area: l1;
}
```

And So on.

Working Demo:

```css
.userdetails_card {
  background: white;
  color: #000;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  clear: both;
  display: table-cell;
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px lightblue;
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-areas: "logo l1 l1" "logo l2 l3" "logo l4 l5" "logo l6 l6";
  justify-items: stretch;
  align-items: center;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.label {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.label1 {
  grid-area: l1;
}

.label2 {
  grid-area: l2;
}

.label3 {
  grid-area: l3;
}

.label4 {
  grid-area: l4;
}

.label5 {
  grid-area: l5;
}

.label6 {
  grid-area: l6;
}

.success {
  background-color: #0ae;
  border-radius: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  border: 4px solid #10e619;
  grid-area: logo;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="userdetails_card">
  <div id="part1" class="success">
    <p>AA</p>
  </div>
  <div class="label label1">
    content for label 1
  </div>
  <div class="label label2">
    content for label 2
  </div>
  <div class="label label3">
    content for label 3
  </div>
  <div class="label label4">
    content for label 4
  </div>
  <div class="label label5">
    content for label 5
  </div>
  <div class="label label6">
    content for label 6
  </div>
</div>
```